# multiple if statements missing data

Tags: mysql, vb.net, if-statement, datareader

Just want to ask why this wont work for me?

I'm trying to bring back data for booking system (or something which like that).

The problem is that it only go to only one if statement and ignore the second one.

Using VB.net and trying to connect to MySQL database.

Thanks all...

Petr

thanks for answers guys i will try all the problem is that if its not = to let say Monday then it should make the color of the check-box white.

I will try the select case and see.

I did some changes add there checkbox lists that it make it easier. The problem is to clear the checkbox on different days.

```
    CheckBoxListMon.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    CheckBoxListMon.Enabled = True
    CheckBoxListMon.ClearSelection()
```

This make the checkbox enabled and not selected but I still cant can't click on them they are disabled.

Anyone have some idea?

```
    Try
        strQuery = "SELECT BookingDate, BookingTime,BookRegUserID,Booked FROM bookings"

        MySQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)

        dbCon.Open()

        DR = MySQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While DR.Read

            bookDate = DR.Item("BookingDate")
            bookTime = DR.Item("BookingTime")
            bookRegID = DR.Item("BookRegUserID")
            booked = DR.Item("Booked")

            Select Case True

                Case bookDate = lblMonday.Text And    CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(test) IsNot Nothing

                    CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Enabled = False
                    CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Selected = True
                    CheckBoxListMon.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Attributes.Add("Style", "color: red;")


                Case bookDate = lblTuesday.Text And CheckBoxListTue.Items.FindByValue(test) IsNot Nothing

                    CheckBoxListTue.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Enabled = False
                    CheckBoxListTue.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Selected = True
                    CheckBoxListTue.Items.FindByValue(bookTime).Attributes.Add("Style", "color: red;")
        End While
        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Isee the problem now. You dont want to flip the comboboxes back if they do not match. Lets say you have Monday Tuesday being returned in your result set. The first row will flip monday to true and tuesday to false, the second will set monday to false - which I do not think you want - and set tuesday to true, leaving everything being decided by the last row. The answer is to set them all to false before processing the rows, and only set to true if you get a match, otherwise ignore it.

```
   CbMon10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    CbMon10.Checked = False
    CbMon10.Enabled = True
    CbTue10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
    CbTue10.Checked = False
    CbTue10.Enabled = True
```

While DR.Read

```
bookDate = DR.Item("BookingDate")
bookTime = DR.Item("BookingTime")
bookRegID = DR.Item("BookRegUserID")
booked = DR.Item("Booked")

    Select Case True
        Case bookDate = lblMonday.Text And bookTime = CbMon10.Text
            CbMon10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            CbMon10.Checked = True
            CbMon10.Enabled = False

        Case bookDate = lblTuesday.Text And bookTime = CbTue10.Text
            CbTue10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            CbTue10.Checked = True
            CbTue10.Enabled = False

    End Select

End While
```

Comment: HI I tried this but its always ignoring the second statement :(

Comment: then the second statement is evaluating to false, put a breakpoint there , try the test in the immediate window

Comment: If the first test is true it will ignore the following

Comment: thank you very much it work!!! Just a quick one i put this code to page load that it will only work on correct dates. I will need to put 10 of these check boxes for each day is there any way that i can use it somehow dynamic? Or i have to code it for each of them? thanks again !!!!!

Comment: glad I could help. YOu could have a sub that accepts a combobox and a boolean and then it sets the properties appropriately. You could even try putting the comboboxes in a list(of T) but that is possibly more work, and more complexity, than it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `if-else-if` ladder like this :

```
 If bookDate = lblMonday.Text And bookTime = CbMon10.Text Then
        CbMon10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        CbMon10.Checked = True
        CbMon10.Enabled = False
 Else If bookDate = lblTuesday.Text And bookTime = CbTue10.Text Then
        CbTue10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        CbTue10.Checked = True
        CbTue10.Enabled = False
 Else
        CbTue10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
        CbTue10.Checked = False
        CbTue10.Enabled = True
 End If
```

Comment: I need that the cbmon and cbtue stay white if its false. this way they wont change :( and stay red forever

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple if's you can use it like this:-

```
  If (bookDate = lblMonday.Text And bookTime = CbMon10.Text) or (bookDate = lblTuesday.Text And bookTime = CbTue10.Text) Then
            CbMon10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            CbMon10.Checked = True
            CbMon10.Enabled = False
        Else

            CbMon10.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
            CbMon10.Checked = False
            CbMon10.Enabled = True
        End If
```